# how to use jquery .data with dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, data-binding, getelementbyid

i am making a game in which i have a "player", the player is a image with jquery `data` attached, i am able to access the `data` when i name the `img` `$playerSprite` **even when using the id** (as opposed to `$playerSprite`) like so

```
function Player() {
    this.inFight = false;
}

player = new Player();
$playerSprite = $("<img>", {
    "id":"test",
    "src": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png",
}).data("model", player);

$("div").append($playerSprite);

alert($("#test").data("model").inFight);
```

however when i create the "player" as a `img` in a `div`, i can access the `img` with the `id` however i cant access the `data` with it. with the below code

```
function Player() {
    this.level = 1;
}

function Game() {
    var player = new Player();
         $("div").html($("<img>", {
            "class": "onTop displayCurrentHealth",
                "src": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png",
                "alt": "you",
                "id": "test"
        }).data("model", player)
        );
}
Game();
$("#test").click(function(){alert("success");});
$("#test").click(function(){alert($(this).data("model").level);});
alert($("#test").data("model").level);
```

if i click on the `img` it alerts "success" and then i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'level' of undefined fiddle.jshell.net/6Erj5/3/show/:40`

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akF2v/6/) and [fiddle with issue](http://jsfiddle.net/6Erj5/3/)

Comment: try $("#test").on('click',function(){alert($(this).data("model").level);

Comment: @Raghu thats not the issue i said already that id does alert "success", (if it works please provide a fiddle, because it must mean something other then i think your saying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are creating two elements on the page with the same id, #test. The first is the static div, then you are adding a child img to it with an id also of test. Invalid html, the jQuery will only find the first test (the div) and you didn't add the data to the div. Change the id of the image, or get the child img of the div eg

```
$('#test').find('img').data('model')
```

Comment: you are right i fixed it (http://jsfiddle.net/6Erj5/5/) it was just a example so i didnt pay attention, thnx im not sure if thats the same problem of my actual game, will be back if i got more issues with this, thnx again.

Comment: ok found my error (in the game) - real stupid like most errors. i didnt change from the old syntax (`objname[prop]`) to the new `$("#player").data("stats")[prop]` wow! humans are dumb! but we learn

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what game you are writing. Is it available to be looked at online. I just recently finished writing a Game (Snakes and ladders board game), did exactly the same thing you did with a player object which had an img, but I never used any data on the actual HTML element, I stored a reference to the img tag on the actual player object, I never liked to put extra data in the DOM. I got canvas and webGL involved too, I would be interested in having a look at your code, if your willing

Comment: lol its a game im making to learn atm but feel free to check it out (you can find it with the link in my profile as well) http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/adventure.html not very exiting (my model for the concepts is from runescape) atm im still using my old script until my new one is fully updated (adventure.js instead of adventuretest.js) and i keep switching to test the new one.

Comment: yep minesweeper has only like 3 lines of jquery but it works, if you look at the code you can see i started making it editable, (size and bombs) but then lost interest.

Comment: so where can i see what you made?

Comment: I would love to show you, but is only deployed internally inside our corporate network I'm afraid, and I will probably breach corporate policy if I deploy publicly I'm afraid

Comment: how nice... well thats the stupid non-sharing world we live in, copyright's, and greed, blah blah etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in this event handler:

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    alert($(this).data("model").level);
});
```

`this` means `#test` which doesn't have any data set to is.
If you change it like this, it should work:

```
$("img").click(function () {
    alert($(this).data("model").level);
});
```

About your question regarding dynamically added elements: please read about event delegation in javascript. Quick example:

```
$(existingParentElement).on('eventType', 'dynamicElement', eventHandler);
```

In your case:

```
$('#test').on('click', 'img', function () {
    alert($(this).data("model").level);
});
```

Comment: you didnt really address the case, just the question, and the crucial point is that there are two elements with `id` of `test`, not very helpful, anyway i already got a good answer. keep trying.

Comment: Yeah, I glanced over the duplicated ids, but still, this is the way to handle events for dynamically added elements. I woudn't say it's not helpful. :P

Comment: not helpful for this question, i know how to add events to dynamically added elements, and as i pointed out the first `onclick` works.